# How to transform a different notation floating point number to double?

Tags: c#

I'm currently trying to convert a few numbers from a DB2 Server into double values in C#.

The getting of the data from the DB2 Server is not a Problem, and I get the data into a DataTable quite easily. The Problem then Comes when I try to convert the objects into double values, as the Notation is different (, instead of . as example).

Thus the code:

```
 foreach (DataRow row in DataTable myResultTable)
 {
     double myValue = String.IsNullOrEmpty(row["myValue"].ToString())? 0 : (double)row["myValue"]; // myValue has 1234,56 as Content.
 }
```

Fails with an exception that the value can't be converted.

The datatype of the field myValue in the db2 is Decimal with a length of 16.

As I didn't find anything, I thought about converting it to string, formating it there and then transform that into a double but that seems quite....complicated to me for something that should be easy (and complicated always means prone to Errors because of something unexpected).

So my question is: Is there any easy way to do this Transformation?

Edit:
As it was asked a GetType on row["myValue"] results in: `{Name = "Decimal" FullName = "System.Decimal"}`.

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. We can then tell you how to parse the string. Right now it's very vague.

Comment: What is the column type of the data in SQL server? Is it really a string type? Or are you converting the result to string for no reason?

Comment: It looks like the decimal point is a comma.  Are you using the correct culture for your PC settings?

Comment: @DanielHilgarth in DB2 ist a decimal  datatype (correcting the question just saw it is from the db2 database not the SQL).

Comment: @Thomas: Please provide a real example. What you show now doesn't make too much sense as `dataTable["myValue"]` will return a `DataColumn` object

Comment: @jdweng the Problem is the pc and the Server seem to have different culture Settings (can't Change either culture Settings there).

Comment: @Thomas: Please let us know what `row["myValue"].GetType()` returns

Comment: @DanielHilgarth tnx was a copy & paste error when I put in the code I used from the program to here ....at least I know now what Enigmativity was trying to say.  And edited the result of gettype intot he question

Comment: @Thomas Please see my answer. You were simply casting to the wrong type

Comment: You need to use Double.ParseExact() to change culture instead of doing a cast.

Comment: @jdweng: Please see my answer. Parsing is not the correct way here.

Comment: @jdweng: It is also incorrect what you say. You can use [`Double.Parse`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t9ebt447(v=vs.110).aspx) just as well if you need to pass a specific culture.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The real solution is to cast to `decimal` not to `double`:

```
var value = row["myValue"] is DBNull ? 0m : (decimal)row["myValue"];
```

Comment: Tnx that worked.....could kick myself there tbh......somehow I was fixated on: decimal on the db must be float/double in c# (completely forgot that c# has ist own decimal datatype).